# Geocoder API keeps giving me Unauthorized 401 error using correct appID and appCode

Tags: c#, rest, json.net, geocoding, here-api

I am currently having an issue with the Geocoder API.  I keep getting an error,  (401) Unauthorized.  I am using the app_ID and app_Code assigned to me.  I have used these with the mapping functionality without issue.

I am trying to build a web application.  I need to retrieve geocoding  coordinates for address.  I am passing an address into the searchtext parameter for the following Geocoder API: https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json

```
using (var w = new WebClient())
    {
       string jsonData = string.Empty;
       string url1 = "https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?app_id= <myAppID>&app_code=myAppCode>&searchtext=3003+N+Central+Ave+Phoenix+AZ+85012&gen=9";

       Uri myOrigin = new Uri(url1);
       string myGeocode = string.Empty;

       JObject myObject = new JObject();

       jsonData = w.DownloadString(myOrigin); //FAILS HERE

       myObject = JObject.Parse(jsonData);

    }
```

I am expecting a json response that contains geocoding coordinates for latitude and longitude.

Comment: Which is the case when I add my credentials and run the request directly: ..."DisplayPosition":{"Latitude":33.48256,"Longitude":-112.0726},"NavigationPosition":[{"Latitude":33.48252,"Longitude":-112.07369}],"MapView":{....}... If you trace the outgoing request does it look correct?

Comment: I ran it yesterday and it wasn't working.   Today it is.    I reran my code and now the error response is gone and the correct response was returned.   Just found out it may have been something on our network end that caused the issue.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is looks like with users credentials, please use the correct app_id/app_code for the request from the project page.

https://developer.here.com/projects

Do let us know if you have further issues.